# How to convert intergers into timestamp?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have

```
year=2021, month=2, date=2, hour=0, minute=0, second=0
```

I want timestamp from these inputs like

```
2021-02-02 00:00:00.000000
```

How to approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
import datetime as dt

result = dt.datetime(year=2021, month=2, day=2, hour=0, minute=0, second=0)

print(result)
#2021-02-02 00:00:00
```

If you want to include microseconds:

```
result = dt.datetime(year=2021, month=2, day=2, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=1)
#2021-02-02 00:00:00.000001
```